# HighCharts: Updating stops in yAxis does not work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am going to change stops values of solid gauge in highcharts gague after creating it. The following code is the code I wrote:

```
this.gaugeChart.yAxis[0].update({
  stops: [
    [0.0, '#55BF3B'],
    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'],
    [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
  ] });
```

The problem is that it does not update the stops values of solid gauge. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/c12ttgh3/4/) and code below. define your chart or if its in chart load function simply user "this" keyword.

```
var chartX=  this.gaugeChart;//  define your chart
$('#somebutton').click(function(){
chartX.yAxis[0].update({
stops: [[0.1, '#a2a2a2'], // grey
       [0.5, '#a2a2a2'], // grey
       [0.9, '#a2a2a2']] // grey
 },false); 
chartX.series[0].bindAxes();
chartX.redraw(true);
});
```